# update_post_meta not working with (custom post type)

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type called (books)

i tried to add new fields to books posts, but when i put the data to the fields it's not saved when i click publish or update the post!

my code working fine with the normal posts, but with books posts no!

anybody have solutions for this please?

```
    add_action("admin_init", "checkbox_init");

function checkbox_init(){
  add_meta_box("checkbox", "book details", "checkbox", "books", "normal", "high");
}

function checkbox(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $mycustomfields_bookname = $custom["mycustomfields_bookname "][0];
  $mycustomfields_youtubeid= $custom["mycustomfields_youtubeid"][0];

echo "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
echo "<label>Book Name</label><br /><input style='text-align:center;' type='text' id='mycustomfields_bookname ' name='mycustomfields_bookname' value='". $mycustomfields_bookname."'/>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<label>Youtube Trailer ID</label><br /><input id='mycustomfields_youtubeid' style='text-align:center;' type='text' name='mycustomfields_youtubeid' value='". $mycustomfields_youtubeid."'/>";
echo "</div>";

}

// Save Meta Details
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata', 100);
function save_details(){
  global $post;
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return $post->ID;
}

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "mycustomfields_bookname", $_POST["mycustomfields_bookname"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "mycustomfields_youtubeid", $_POST["mycustomfields_youtubeid"]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata', 100);` function name is `save_metadata` but your function named as `save_details`. And in `save_post` hooks present parameter `$post`. **Don't use `global $post`**.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_details', 100, 3 );
function save_details( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, "mycustomfields_bookname", $_POST["mycustomfields_bookname"] );
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, "mycustomfields_youtubeid", $_POST["mycustomfields_youtubeid"] );
}
```

I think this should work.

Option with first parametr `$post_id`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_details', 100);
function save_details( $post_id ) {

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, "mycustomfields_bookname", $_POST["mycustomfields_bookname"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "mycustomfields_youtubeid", $_POST["mycustomfields_youtubeid"] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim, it's working fine now, omg i tried to many ways to fix that but did not work, thanks mate!